# Configure wireless network from the command line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, networkmanager

I know I can use ifconfig to configure my ethernet network interfaces. But can I also configure my wireless network interfaces using ifconfig. (It seems to be listed as eth1 in ifconfig output, why is that ?) Specifically :

1. How do I check from command line if my wireless is enabled
2. How do I enable / disable the wireless using commandline
3. Out of a few available wireless networks how do I chose one and connect to it
4. How do I configure the parameters (like username, password, security settings and certificate information) from the command line
5. Sometimes an available wireless network is not visible for some reason. In such a case, I select "Connect to hidden wireless network" and type the name of the connection. How do I do the same from my terminal
6. I recently installed xmonad, I'd like to know how to start the graphical network manager from command line
7. How do I change my system-wide proxy settings from command line ?

(I am using Ubuntu natty.)

Comment: If you want pure CLI you'll need to stop network-manager; then you'll need iwconfig to manage wireless settings. And ifconfig to configure your interface IP settings (or dhcpclient if there is a dhcpd around). Also you should look at the wpa_supplicant command for WPA stuff if you need to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since version 0.8.1, Network Manager comes with a command line tool, [`nmcli`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/nmcli.1.html). Its capabilities in older versions are very limited; for the most part, you can use it to view available connections and switch between them but not configure new ones. Since version 0.9.6, [`nmcli` can create new connections](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80126/how-to-connect-to-internet-using-nmcli).

There are other, third-party command-line interfaces to Network Manager. [Cnetworkmanager](http://vidner.net/martin/software/cnetworkmanager/) has more features than `nmcli`; in particular, it allows defining connections and specifying wifi encryption keys.

An alternative to Network Manager is [Wicd](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/), which provides both an X interface and a console interface.

If you want to do things “by hand”, the main tools you'll need to know are:

- [`ifconfig`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/ifconfig.8.html) for general information and activation of network interfaces.
- [`iwconfig`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/iwconfig.8.html) for settings that are specific to wifi interfaces, in particular the ESSID (network name) and [WEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy) keys.
- [`iwlist`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/iwlist.8.html) to get information about possible settings for a wireless interface (in particular `iwlist scan` to show available networks). A hidden network is one that won't show up on `iwlist scan` but still works when selected with `iwconfig`.
- [Wpa_supplicant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wpa_supplicant) to configure [WPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access)-protected networks.

<sub>Some of your questions are completely unrelated to wifi configuration, so I'm not going to answer them here. Please don't ask unrelated questions in the same post.</sub>

Comment: isn't `ifconfig` deprecated in favour of `iproute2`?

Comment: @jasonwryan No, why should it be? `ifconfig` is a small tool for a dedicated purpose. `ip` is a Swiss army knife. They don't play in the same category. The author of `ip` does consider `ifconfig` and friends to be “legacy”, but the rest of the world seems fairly attached to this legacy.

Comment: Arch went that way, also Debian: "our plans are to replace net-tools completely with iproute, maybe leading the route for other distributions to follow." http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2009/03/msg00780.html I figured it was inevitable...

Comment: @jasonwryan Considering that `ifconfig` (and `route` and `netstat`) [“have a very long history, and are extremely well known by many sysadmins, and used in many, *many* shell scripts”](http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2009/03/msg01248.html), including [many Debian package maintenance scripts](http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2009/03/msg01242.html), it'll take a very long time to get anywhere close to deprecating them.

Comment: ...so, that's a "yes" but not in my lifetime? :)