# Can't login to Linux Mint 17.2 after "complete remove" of libimobiledevice

Tags: linux-mint

I was having this problem (trust issues with apple device and linux):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241604/trust-this-computer-iphone-4-and-linux-mint-17-2-with-libimobiledevice-1-1-6

I decided to "completely remove" all of those packages listed ie:

libimobiledevice-utils: 1.1.6+git20140213~ppa10
libimobiledevice4: 1.1.6+git20140213~ppa10
libplist1: 1.12~ppa4
ideviceinstaller: 1.0.1-0.2

My intention was to re-install them, hoping it would fix the issue.

I restarted the machine and now I can't login - after I enter my password at the login screen, it just quickly displays a black screen with:

```
Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela pc-name tty1  
pc-name login:
```

And then goes back to the login screen.

I'm wondering if `cinnamon` was perhaps uninstalled as a related package?

Can anyone tell me how I can somehow login and reinstall those packages?

**System Info**

Operating System: Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon 64-bit

Cinnamon Version: 2.6.13

Linux Kernel: 3.16.0-29-generic

Comment: tried reinstalling said packages from a terminal and rebooting?

Comment: could u perhaps direct me to how to undo the "complete removals" I did in synaptic package manager, via the terminal?  I haven't found directions yet on Google (from my phone).

Comment: `/var/log/apt/history.log` might be what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

This worked for me.

01)  Hit `ctrl` + `alt` + `f1` on startup (make sure Function Lock is on).
02)  Login at `tty1`.
03)  Connect to wifi with:

`nmcli c up uuid`

For more details on this last step see:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158747/92486

04)  Re-install these packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice4
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-utils  
sudo apt-get install libplist1
sudo apt-get install ideviceinstaller

// and i had to install cinnamon again

sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

05)  Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

Further Information:

`Mark For Complete Removal` on `libimobiledevice4` causes:

[image]

`Mark For Complete Removal` on `libplist1` causes:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> on startup (make sure Function Lock is on).
2. Login at tty1.
3. ```
   sudo apt-get install cinnamon
   ```
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

Now try logging in.