# Basic network via command line

Tags: networking, command-line, fedora

I am using Fedora 23. Using the file explorer I "found" this page

> [image: !["other locations"]

It shows where I can access other networks, I can click on them, and log in...

My questions is: **Is there an equivalent place I can reach via command line?**

That I can log into a network and such....

I am currently under the impression that I would need to mount the network to a file?

My goal right now is to use the command line as much as possible, so if there are any relevant commands, or resources please point me to them as well...

Side question: can I log into a WiFi network via command line? I am currently under the impression that I would need to mount the network to file as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your GUI explorer is using information from the [avahi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_(software)) daemon which is listening for services on the local network. You can do the same from the cli with

```
avahi-browse -rat
```

Answer (score 0):

You can list other networks in cli using `nmcli`.

```
nmcli con show
```

or

```
nmcli d
```

Then you need to copy your UUID for further connect to the ones-needed interface.

```
nmcli c up uuid <paste uuid here>
```

or

```
nmcli -p con up "my-eth1" ifname eth1
```

About resources: you can get acquainted at first with this: [nmcli](http://www.tecmint.com/configure-network-connections-using-nmcli-tool-in-linux/), than you can go further and use this [nmcli_fedora23](http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Fedora_23&p=initial_conf&f=3).

By the way you can deeper cut through http://unix.stackexchange.com - for example [connect through cli](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92799/connecting-to-wifi-network-through-command-line)