# how to repair or reinstall kde noen with live-boot

Tags: kde, kde-neon

i am using kde-neon. today i wanted to uninstall vlc and i used this command:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge vlc
```

so os borke :) and now i cant log in to my desktop (log in page don't show and it is balck)

i tryed to reinstall kde-desktop by alt+ctrl+f1 (command line page) but i'm not connected to wifi and i can't fix it

now how can I connect to wifi in command line or reinstall kde-desktop or kde-neon with live-boot?

if i want to install windows10 or another distro how i can save my files that was saved in home directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to connect to Wifi You can follow the following answer on SE:

[Connecting to wifi network through command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92799/connecting-to-wifi-network-through-command-line)

Then You should be able to reinstall KDE.

Also, in order to deinstall VLC You could use

```
sudo apt purge VLC
```

or

```
sudo apt-get purge VLC
```

The command according to man page:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

> autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other
>              packages and are now no longer needed as dependencies changed or the package(s) needing them were removed in the
>              meantime.
>
> You should check that the list does not include applications you have grown to like even though they were once
>              installed just as a dependency of another package. You can mark such a package as manually installed by using
>              apt-mark(8). Packages which you have installed explicitly via install are also never proposed for automatic
>              removal.